# no such file to load -- sequel/adapters/ and Invalid DATABASE_URL with heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku, spree

I am creating a spree application. Now I need to push my local db to heroku shared database. When I ran heroku db:push I got below error

!!! Caught Server Exception
HTTP CODE: 500
Taps Server Error: LoadError: no such file to load -- sequel/adapters/
["/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:249:in `require'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:249:in`block in tsk_require'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:72:in `block in check_requiring_thread'",

Then I tried to check my shared database url in heroku config. But i didn't found in config vars

Can anyone help me out to solve this issue?

Comment: What's the command line you are using to push the data?

Comment: I was looking for the database URL you were using for heroku db:push.  If you are calling it without a URL, you need to post the contents of your config/database.yml file.

Comment: Yeah.. exactly.. I didn't passed any arguments with that command. As I had a valid database.yml in my path.. it considered it as a DB to push

Answer (score 3):

Check that you actually have a Shared Database addon listed when you do;

```
heroku info
```

If you don't for whatever reason then you need to do

```
heroku addons:add shared-database
```

to add it and then try your push again. Although I can't think why you app wouldn't have the shared db on initial creation.

Comment: thnx john for quick response.. actually I can't wait or can't spend more time to figure out that issue. So I just destroyed that app from heroku, created a seperate gemset and then run bundler and created heroku app. And then it worked fine.. So is it possible there may be dependency collision in postgresql gems??

Comment: When I did heroku info it is showing me database size : (empty). Why ?